# What happened to my duck?

Tags: flavor, oven, roasting, duck

This happened a couple of years ago, but I still don't have an answer. Christmas eve. I had a duck in the oven. I tried to cook it at a slightly lower temperature and a little longer than the recipe dictated. Also, I didn't turn the duck over at all.

The duck was completely done. My wife complained about the horrible taste of the breast, while I was happily eating the leg. Later on I found that the breast was foul smelling and tasting...

Any idea why this would happen? Did I cook too long, should I have turned the duck over, why should the leg be tasty and the breast foul???

Comment: A bad duck maybe?  Have you tried again?

Comment: Was it stuffed?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the recipe?

Comment: No I haven't tried a whole duck again. It wasn't stuffed. I have no idea which recipe it was. This happened about two years ago.

Comment: It might have been a bad duck. That would have been bad luck. During Christmas season.

Comment: I've experienced this with duck before - it comes out tasting mostly like liver. I recommend marinating and stuffing to ensure it doesn't become too dry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you didn't do some kind of "flavor injection" treatment, there is absolutely no reason why one part of a bird would taste radically different from another. I'm going to go with "Bad Duck."

Cooking the bird slowly seriously reduces the possibility of a "hot spot" causing some kind of local taste variance. Breast meat will become overdone at the point where dark meat is still tasty, but that wouldn't explain smell or taste, and unpleasant *smells* are almost always related to bacterial issues.

If it was discolored, it could have been local bruising, which would cause some taste issues, but, again, wouldn't explain the smell.

Comment: I'll try another duck next Christmas :) Nope, I'll try another duck before Christmas.

Answer (score 5):

You could have bought a wild duck. They can taste very fishy, particularly in the breast meat. The traditional way of getting the fishy taste out of wild duck is to cook it with a potato in the cavity but I don't think this makes very much difference.

Comment: I never knew that. I believe I bought a farm-bred duck.

Comment: @GUI Junkie: If the duck came to you with feathers and bullet holes, it was probably wild. Otherwise, it was almost certainly farmed.

Comment: Haha, then it was farmed. No doubt.